# I'm getting exceptions committing objects to the database via nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm trying to save a parent object and it's child to an SQL Server DB via nHibernate. 
  The structure in the DB of these 2 objects is as follows: 
The parent (application) table's primary key is 'Id' which is a foreign key to the child (application_certificate) table where it is also called 'Id'. 
In addition, the child table has the column 'Id' as a composite primary key along with another column.
  I get no exceptions if I create and save an application. However, if I try to associate a certificate with it, I get the following exception:

> Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [Order.ApplicationCertificate#Order.ApplicationCertificate]

The hbm.xml files (with the concerned parts only) are as follows:

Application.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <hibernate-mapping assembly="sApp" namespace="Order" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
      <class name="Application" table="application" lazy="false" dynamic-insert="true" >
        <id name="Id" column="id" />
        <bag name="ApplicationCertificates" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true">
          <key column="id" />
          <one-to-many class="ApplicationCertificate" />
        </bag>
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

application_certificate.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="sApp" namespace="Order" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="ApplicationCertificate" table="application_certificate" lazy="false" dynamic-insert="true" optimistic-lock="version" dynamic-update="true">
    <!--optimistic-lock="version"-->

    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="Id" column="id" />
      <key-property name="CertificateNumber" column="certificate_number" />
    </composite-id>

    <!-- must be first element after id-->
    <version column="version" name="Version" />

    <many-to-one name="Application">
      <column name="id" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Where is the `Version` for Application, please paste the Entity too

Comment: Hi Paul. Application has no version column. What do you mean by entity in this context?

Comment: I mean `Class`, and what is your version column type and version field type?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The version column is a not-null int. The entity classes are as follows:      `public class Application  
    {  

        #region Constructor  
        public Application()
        {            
        } 
        #endregion

        #region Mapped Properties
        public virtual int Id { get; set; } // for NHibernate
        public virtual IList<ApplicationCertificate> ApplicationCertificates { get; set; }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this change seems to make it work:

```
<composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="Application" class="Application" column="id" />
      <key-property name="CertificateNumber" column="certificate_number" />
    </composite-id>

    <!-- must be first element after id-->
    <version column="version" name="Version" />

    <property name="Id" update="false" insert="false" >
      <column name="id" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </property>
```